# Sum of rows with certain values T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Thanks for all the fast and great answers. But I just found out that in my case, the example table I gave were not correct enough to describe the true situation, so I updated it again. New updated table shown below.

---

I am having the following queries:

temporary table `#d` to list the selected domains, temporary table `#total` to list the total value of these domains and temporary table `#speed` to list the speeds of these domains.

Then

```
SELECT domains, total, speed
FROM #d AS d
LEFT JOIN #total AS t ON d.domains = t.domains
LEFT JOIN #speed as S ON d.domains = s.domains
ORDER BY d.domains DESC
```

The result is as followings:

```
 Domains   Total  Speed 
 -----------------------
 XYZ AB        10     1
 XYZ CD        12     2
 XYZ EF        14     3
 Bhzu           6     4
 Cjuki         19     5
```

What I wish to have is the SUM of `XYZ AB`, `XYZ CD` and `XYZ EF` like this:

```
Domains   Total    Speed   Rate (Speed/Total)
---------------------------------------------
 XYZ        36       6          6/36
 Bhzu       6        4          4/6
 Cjuki      19       5          5/19
```

In the reality, there is some other rows with some other length of Names of domains.

This will be an SSRS automated generation Report, I am using T-SQL.

How could I make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: why is the total 35 and not 36 (10+12+14)

Comment: I updated your Total for A to be 36 to match the sum from your source table.  Sorry if that is not right!

Comment: @JamesCooke sorry, bad maths XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the part of the domain that follows the (first) dot, and group by that, you can do:

```
select x.domain, 
    sum(t.total) total, 
    sum(s.speed) speed,
    1.0 * sum(s.speed) / sum(t.total) rate
from #d as d 
cross apply (values (left(d.domains, charindex('.', d.domains + '.') - 1))) x(domain)
left join #total as t on d.domains = t.domains 
left join #speed as s on d.domains = s.domains 
group by x.domains
order by d.domains desc
```

The upside is that this works regardless of how many characters there are before the dot.

Comment: Thanks, but I am so sorry that it was my bad that I didn't give a good example of the table. It could be problematic with the LEFT() query in the reality. I just updated the question.

Comment: @Olivia: so basically the separator is the space, not the dot. If so, you can just change `charindex('.', d.domains + '.')` with `charindex(' ', d.domains + ' ')`, and leave the rest of the query unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is literally in the form `A.a`, you could replace `Domains` with `LEFT(Domains, 1)`, and group by that, then replace `Total` and `Speed` with `SUM(Total)` and `SUM(Speed)`.

```sql
SELECT LEFT(domains,1), SUM(total), SUM(speed)
FROM #d AS d
LEFT JOIN #total AS t ON d.domains=t.domains
LEFT JOIN #speed as S ON d.domains=s.domains
GROUP BY LEFT(domains,1)
ORDER BY LEFT(domains,1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am so sorry that it was my bad that I didnt give a good example of the table. It could be problematic with the LEFT() query in the reality. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT domains,total, speed
FROM #d AS d
LEFT JOIN #total AS t ON d.domains=t.domains
LEFT JOIN #speed as S ON d.domains=s.domains
)
    SELECT LEFT(Domains, CHARINDEX('.', Domains) -1) AS DOMAINS, SUM(Total) AS TOTAL, SUM(Seed) AS SPEED, 1.0 * SUM(Total) AS TOTAL, SUM(Seed) AS RATE
    FROM  T
    GROUP BY LEFT(Domains, CHARINDEX('.', Domains) -1)
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't give a very clear example of the table. In the reality there is some more rows with same or longer domain names as the example. I just updated the question and example.